# Python Numpy .dot()

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

Есть 2 массива:

```
a1 = [[0.1], [0.2], [0.3], [0.4], [0.5], [0.6], [0.7], [0.8], [0.9]]
a2 = [1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0]
```

И функция

```
print(np.dot(a1[2], a2))
```

В консоли вижу это:

```
print(np.dot(a1[2], a2))
  File "<__array_function__ internals>", line 6, in dot
ValueError: shapes (1,) and (4,) not aligned: 1 (dim 0) != 4 (dim 0)
```

Как исправить? Есть ли альтернатива?

Если заменю первый массив на этот:

```
a1 = [
    [0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1], 
    [0.2,0.2,0.2,0.2], 
    [0.3,0.3,0.3,0.3],  
    [0.4,0.4,0.4,0.4],  
    [0.5,0.5,0.5,0.5],  
    [0.6,0.6,0.6,0.6],  
    [0.7,0.7,0.7,0.7],  
    [0.8,0.8,0.8,0.8],  
    [0.9,0.9,0.9,0.9]
]
```

То все работает правильно, но если есть вариант с начальным массивом, то было бы удобнее

Comment: print(np.dot(a1[2][0], a2))

Comment: а что вы собственно пытаетесь сделать? получить скалярное произведение векторов или перемножить матрицы или умножить вектор/матрицу на скаляр?